Why is the work done by a force on a rigid body zero if the displacement of point of application of force is zero?
There have been previous questions asked similar to this question, but I couldn't understand the concept properly. Please help me get it.
There is a rod hinged at a point with no friction present on the hinged point. It is said that as the displacement of the point of application of the hinged force is zero, then the work done by the hinged force on the whole system of rod will be zero. Why is that? Why can't we take the force to be acting on the center of mass and consider its displacement and then calculate the work done? Similar is the case when a circular body moves on a horizontal plane: if it purely rolls, the work done by the friction (which is static in this case) is zero at the point of contact, where friction acts, and never slips.
Edit: I want to know that to calculate the work done on the hinged rod under gravity, should I calculate the work done by gravity on center of mass in a linear way ( Work done = mgh , h: center of mass displaced with "h" height vertically,  L: length of rod ) as under constant force only the displacement in the direction of force matters, or whether to calculate the work done by torque of gravity acting on center of mass with the distance from the hinged point ( Work done = mgL/2*cos(theta)*d(theta), assume theta: angle of rod w.r.t its initial horizontal position ) or we can go either way and why not both?
I am not sure about calculating work done because the book says that as the CoM has fallen through height h, then work done by the force of gravity is simply : mgh, and it gets converted to its rotational kinetic energy: 1/2I(omega)^2, I : moment of inertia of rod, omega: angular velocity of rod ), please explain.

how can you cconclude that the hinge point moved the center of mass?

Center of mass will only be affected by the external forces, only weight and hinged force acts on the rod whose net acceleration can be seen in the resultant of radial acceleration and tangential acceleration of the centre of mass of rod.

The work done by a force refers to the displacement vector of the application point of that force: you cannot arbitrarily change it. So it is wrong to use the displacement vector of the center of mass. Using the wrong point would produce mistakes when applying mechanical energy balance  laws like “total work done by all internal and external forces amounts to the variation of kinetic energy”.
(There is an exception regarding a uniform gravitational field, where the total work  of gravitational forces coincides with the work on the center of mass as if all the system were concentrated there, but it is not the case here.)
In the present ideal case, the application point is always at rest so that the work done by the force acting on it is zero. In concrete cases, the application point is not a geometric point but it has an extended structure and work could be done by reactive forces if the constraint is not frictionless.

But if I take Work done by all the forces for the displacement of Center of Mass then it will contribute to the Translational kinetic energy of the body and work done by the torque of the forces about the center of mass will contribute to the Rotational kinetic energy of the body about the centre of mass. Which is true. Isn't it?

The work correctly computed — that is using the displacement of each application point which is different of the center of mass —  equals the variation of the total kinetic energy. (This latter can be decomposed as the sum of the kinetic energy of the center of mass plus the kinetic energy around it.) Instead it seems to me that you are computing the total work as if the forces were all applied on the center of mass. With this prescription, the identity above would be false (instead it is true).

@Maximal ideal Please do not add further issues: here we are discussing mechanical systems.

I do not understand well the nature of your point. You should agree with these results. The center of mass moves as if all external forces were applied to it as a point of mass equal to the mass of the system. The total work done by internal and external forces on the system equals the variation of total kinetic energy of the system. However, If the body is rigid, internal forces responsible for rigidity have zero total work so they do not give contribution. The kinetic energy can be decomposed as the kinetic energy of the center of mass and the kinetic energy around it.


Why is the work done by a force on a rigid body is zero if the
displacement of point of application of force is zero?

Because in order for the force to do work on a body, the source of that force must transfer energy to that body. Energy transfer will not occur unless there is displacement of the point of application of the force on the body. The hinge in your example does no work on the rod because it has not transferred any energy to the rod.
As another example, consider an ice skater who pushes off a wall in the rink causing the skater to accelerate away from the wall and acquire kinetic energy. The skater pushes on the wall with a force $F$. Per Newton's 3rd law the wall exerts an equal and opposite force $F$ on the skater.
During the time the wall exerts the force on the skater, the skater's hands are in contact with the wall. There is no displacement of the skaters hands while in contact with the wall. When the skaters hand separate from the wall, the wall no longer exerts a force on the skater. The wall transfers no energy to the skater. The wall does no work.
The skater has acquired kinetic energy due to the conversion of chemical potential energy in the skaters muscles to kinetic energy of the skater as a whole.
Hope this helps.

But the force exerted by the hinge on rod gets transferred through the body to provide centripetal acceleration to the centre of mass and also contribute to the tangential acceleration alongwith the force due to gravity in the case of hinged rod.

@Raja The centripetal force is perpendicular to the motion of the particle so it does no work. The tangential acceleration is independent of the centripetal acceleration

Meant motion of the end of the rod

So, the work is done by the transferred force's tangential component at all the element particles of rigid body's displacement.

@Raja Not sure I follow you, but the tangential acceleration is the result of the work done by gravity only.  The hinge does not do work to produce tangential acceleration.

The reasonsing is slightly more complex.  I have drawn the situation in a figure. The force $\vec F$, which I define as the force exerted by the hinge on the pendulum, is always parallel to the rod. You could replace the rod by a rope and it would only provide tension, which would be parallel. Another way to see it would be that if this were not the case, the hinge could create a torque. You can imagine a rusty hinge with a lot of friction that could hold the rod parallel, which means it is providing a torque. But here we are imagining a frictionless hinge.
The work done over some displace $\vec s$ is given by
$$W=\vec F\cdot \vec s.$$
The center of mass is always rotating around the hinge, so that means the velocity is always perpendicular to vector connecting the hinge and the center of mass. This means that the velocity is always perpendicular to the force. Over some small timestep $\Delta t$, the displacement can be approximated by $\vec s\approx \vec v\Delta t$. This means the displacement is always perpendicular to the force provided by the hinge, which means the work done by the hinge is always zero!


The work you are considering is not the one of the constraint force. The force acts on an extreme of the pendulum not on the center of mass.

You can displace a force vector along itself without changing its physical meaning. The force still creates the same acceleration and torque. Regardless of that, if I had drawn the force at the hinge, the reasoning would be the same.

If you consider a solid body with a form different of a rod you cannot conclude that the work done by the reactive force at the hinge is orthogonal to the CM displacement and your reasoning fails regarding work. In computing the work the application point matters. That is what I wanted to stress.
